# The statically inserted items in combobox doubles on button click for more than once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a combobox that has following items inserted

```
public void SetOperationDropDown()
    {
    //ByDefault the selected text in the cmbOperations will be -SELECT OPERATIONS-.
    cmbOperations.SelectedItem = "-SELECT OPERATIONS-";

    //This is for adding four operations with value in operation dropdown
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(0, "PrimaryKeyTables");
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(1, "NonPrimaryKeyTables");
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(2, "ForeignKeyTables");
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(3, "NonForeignKeyTables");
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(4, "UPPERCASEDTables");
    cmbOperations.Items.Insert(5, "lowercasedtables");
    }
```

But as the user clicks on the button more than once the value gets doubled or any unwanted thing happens to the value.

the button click is

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Function call for validating the textboxes entry
    ValidateForm();

    //Variable to store server address
    string localHost = "192.168.10.3";

    //Variable to store userId and password of the database
    string logInDetails = "gp";

    try
        {
        //Checking for the Valid entries in textboxes if all entries are correct then call functions accordingly
        if((txtPassword.Text == logInDetails) && (txtUsername.Text == logInDetails) && (txtHost.Text == localHost))
            {

            //If connected then give this message to user
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "You are connected to the SQL Server....";

            if(lblMessage.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                //Function call for binding the dropdown with all DB names 
                BindDBDropDown();

                //Function call for binding the operation names in dropdown 
                SetOperationDropDown();

                }
            }
        else
            {
            //Else give the error message to user
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Credentials";
            }
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
        {
        //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
        EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
        log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
        log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What value gets doubled? And can you explain a bit more in detail what "any unwanted thing" is?

Comment: the items in the cmbOperations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void SetOperationDropDown()
{
if(CmbOperations.Items.Count == 0)
{
//ByDefault the selected text in the cmbOperations will be -SELECT OPERATIONS-. 
cmbOperations.SelectedItem = "-SELECT OPERATIONS-"; 
//This is for adding four operations with value in operation dropdown 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(0, "PrimaryKeyTables"); 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(1, "NonPrimaryKeyTables"); 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(2, "ForeignKeyTables"); 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(3, "NonForeignKeyTables"); 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(4, "UPPERCASEDTables"); 
cmbOperations.Items.Insert(5, "lowercasedtables"); 


}
else
{
int? cbSelectedValue = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbOperations.SelectedValue))
cbSelectedValue = convert.toInt32(cmbOperations.SelectedValue);
}
//load your combo again
if(cbSelectedValue != null)
cmbOperations.SelectedValue = cbSelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

There may be small syntax errors since I didn't used VS.

Answer (score 0):

only call the `SetOperationDropDown()` when the load of your page is not a `postback`

```
 if (!IsPostBack) {
    SetOperationDropDown();
 }
```

Comment: Or do a crappy hack and clear items before populating the ComboBox: `cmbOperations.Items.Clear()` :)

Comment: clearing it is not a good idea, because in that case, the 'selected' value will be 'forgotten'

Comment: `IsPostBack` will not be a valid concept in a winforms application.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when the user clicks it, reset the cmbOperations SelectItem to your "do nothing" value, reenable the button when you've finished processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged under WinForms, so I don't think post backs are applicable here. Looking in your `btnStartAnalysis_Click` method, I don't see it calling `SetOperationDropDown`.  Try going into DEBUG mode and put a break point in `SetOperationDropDown`.  Then click your button and see whether your break point is hit.  If it is, then refer to your stack trace to see where `SetOperationDropDown` is being called from.

If the WinForms tag is incorrect and you're actually using WebForms/ASP.NET, then do what Stefanvds and Marcel suggested.  But I think it's important to figure out where `SetOperationDropDown` is being incorrectly called from.